# Passing state to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm refactoring some code to make a more aesthetically pleasing render of a table. I will link a codesandbox that shows both the old and new implementations.

So if you select the two dropdowns at the top, in the old implementation section when you check one of the boxes next to the `fieldName` you will see 3 additional input boxes appear; `lengthType`, `size`, and `maxArrayElements`. The change handlers for these are in the main component `index.js`.

I have since made a separate component `TableRowWithCheckbox` that introduces some new functionality that uses a checkbox to keep track of what row is selected.

In the new implementation (the table) I have decided to render the 3 inputs mentioned above, inside the table. I'm having trouble keeping track of the inputs since they are now moved inside this new component.

Should I initialize state for `lengthType`, `size,` and `maxArrayElements` inside this new component then have the change handler inside the main component? Or initialize the state values AND have the change handles in the main component?

`TableRowWithCheckbox` component below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Checkbox, Dropdown, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

const lengthTypeOptions = [
  { key: "fixed", text: "Fixed", value: "fixed" },
  { key: "variable", text: "Variable", value: "variable" }
];

export default class TableRowWithCheckbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { initialState } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      fieldCheckbox: initialState
    };
  }

  checkbox = () => {
    this.setState({ fieldCheckbox: !this.state.fieldCheckbox }, () => {
      console.log("checkbox --> ", this.state.fieldCheckbox);
      const {
        name,
        dataType,
        isArray,
        position,
        box,
        lengthType,
        size,
        maxArrayElements
      } = this.props;
      box({
        name,
        dataType,
        isArray,
        position,
        isChecked: this.state.fieldCheckbox,
        lengthType,
        size,
        maxArrayElements
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      dataType,
      isArray,
      position,
      lengthType,
      size,
      maxArrayElements
    } = this.props;
    const { fieldCheckbox } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Table.Row>
          <Checkbox
            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
            checkbox
            onChange={this.checkbox}
          />
          <Table.Cell>{name}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{dataType}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{JSON.stringify(isArray)}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{position}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Dropdown
              placeholder="Pick a length Type:"
              clearable
              selection
              search
              fluid
              noResultsMessage="Please search again"
              multiple={false}
              value={this.state.lengthType}
              options={lengthTypeOptions}
              header="CHOOSE A LENGTH TYPE"
              onChange={this.props.updateLengthType}
              required
            />
          </Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Input
              onChange={this.props.onSizeChange}
              type="number"
              name="size"
              min="1"
              placeholder="1"
              required
            />
          </Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Input
              onChange={this.props.onChangeMaxArrayElements}
              type="number"
              name="maxArrayElements"
              placeholder="1"
              min="1"
              max="100"
              required
            />
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4033pyokww)

Comment: Welp. I was missing `handleChange={this.handleChange}` prop when using the `TableRowWithCheckbox` component inside the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

The convention for passing state to a parent is via callback methods.  The parent should pass the child a function to call when there is something to update; and the parameters passed into the function would be ones you want to set in the parent state. That way the parent's method would just need to call this.setState() with the params coming into the function.

Answer (score 0):

In React,  idea is to lift your state up where you will actually modify it. So in your case, it makes sense to have your state and change handlers both inside of your main component.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function as prop to your component, and give your input the same names as in the parent state.

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}
```

Use the function in your inputs

```
<input onChange={this.props.onChange} ... />
```

Comment: yeah, but you are using three functions?, you can use one function.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the values logged, when they are interacted with.

Comment: There may be a binding issue with `this`?

Comment: I tried your example but everytime, I type something the page goes blank.

Comment: Try refreshing? I may have made some breaking changes then reverted. Or try forking the example

Comment: I was missing the change handler inside my child component when using it inside the parent component.